# Do class names change when using directives?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a strange issue where if I try to use a directive the tabs don't work (even though the URL does change), I presume this is because the class name has changed. Also the javascript that I have for effects on my log in form doesn't seem to work which I presume is due to the changed class names too, because it seems to me that it searches the DOM for an element by it's class name. I attach my code below:

My **login.html**:

[image]

My **index.html**:

[image]

My **index.js** (This is the code I got off the internet which I think is searching the DOM by class name):

[image]

Comment: You can do most of that with CSS only.

Comment: Hi jedifans, you're right that it can probably be done using CSS, but I have code (index.js) that already works when not using the directive?, so why reinvent the wheel?